# Why do lower tooth extractions heal slower?

Tags: oral-health

My dentist said upper teeth extractions heal much faster than lower teeth extractions. Sure enough my upper wisdom sockets have completely healed and lower socket is still healing.

I would like to learn the reasons for this.

Answer (score 1):

Though I couldn't find the exact reason or a well written reason for this question. But I have a significant difference  between upper jaw, i.e. maxilla and lower jaw, i.e. mandible.

The maxilla has rich blood supply than mandible. 
Only one major artery- inferior alveolar artery supplies mandible, giving of its small branches.

However maxilla is supplied by three major arteries, viz 
1) Posterior superior alveolar artery
2) Middle superior alveolar artery
3) Anterior superior alveolar artery

And for the venous drainage maxilla has got a plexus of posterior superior, middle superior and anterior superior veins.
Whereas mandible has only got inferior alveolar vein as the sole collector.
(Reference- [kenhub- Innervation and blood supply of the teeth](https://www.kenhub.com/en/library/anatomy/innervation-and-blood-supply-of-the-teeth)
Author: Alexandra Sieroslawska MD)

Now more the blood supply, faster will be the healing ( Though there are lots of articles to support this. One article-
[Checklist for Factors Affecting Wound Healing
Thomas Hess, Cathy BSN, RN, CWOCN](https://doi.org/10.1097/01.ASW.0000396300.04173.ec))
This is because blood caries important nutrients needed for wound healing, eg amino acids, vitamins etc.
I hope I have answered your question :)

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. When adding references, can you please (at least) add a link to the document referenced where available? It does 2 things. It first of all highlights references, and it also makes it easier for the reader to read your references. I have edited this answer to help with that

Comment: @chris sure. I will take care of this next time. Thanks Chris.